# Http status code from a global @ExceptionHandler with the @ControllerAdvice annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a **global exception handler inside a *Spring Boot App*, with the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation**, and I'd like to know, how could I get the http status code for showing a different message when it's 404 and to persist a log with the error, in other cases.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ... 

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
    model.addObject("trace", trace);
    model.addObject("path",  path);
    //model.addObject("status", response.getStatus());

    model.setViewName("error");

    return model;
}
```

I've tried this approach, without success:

```
Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());
```

To get the request attribute, this other name; `javax.servlet.error.status_code` doesn't work either.

Comment: one of your controller/service/dao should be throwing some exception with status code then only you can get that status code in golbal exception handler else there is no way to get status code, since status codes are related to http call.

Comment: Your answer @Praveen Kumar Mekala makes sense, I will go on without the status code at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your own status code corresponding every exception that you are handling. If any exception missed, default will be 5.x.x server error.

Comment: I've tried it, but I always get a 200 response, therefore I guess the code doesn't belong to the http call, that raises the error.

Comment: You have to set your own status code corresponding every exception that you are handling. If any exception missed, default will be 5.x.x server error.

Comment: I may be missing something, because without setting any status code, with  `response.getStatus()` I'm always getting a 200. I guess this 200 answer, comes from the call to the `/error` page.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing this by extracting the expected exception to a separate class that extends Exception. 
By doing this, you can add @ResponseStatus to set your required status code. 
This custom exception can be thrown in your controller needed.

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Person Not Found") 
public class PersonNotFoundException extends Exception {

    public PersonNotFoundException (int id){
        super("PersonNotFoundException with id="+id);
    }
}
```

Instead of specifying the generic RunTime exception, handle the PersonNotFoundException in your @ExceptionHandler and add the exception object to your ModelAndView.